# What alterations to the human body would bioengineers make to increase the survival rate of humans on this planet

Tags: science-based, biology, technology, earth-like, space-colonization

In my world a group of humans led by several bioengineers have crashed on a planet just like earth except that it has seasons that last several hundred years. What alterations to the human biology could the engineers change to make human survival easier on this planet?

Comment: We know absolutely nothing about the biology of the organisms on this planet of yours. We know nothing about differences in atmospheric composition either. I assume in the summers it will be very hot. In the winters very cold. Humans have survived in both frigid and blistering hot environments before without genetic alterations. Surely there are other animals (can't survive without protein) and some sort of plant (fruits and veggies), and as long as humans can catch these beasts and get these foods we need not alter our genes.

Comment: Assume it just like earth

Comment: @DJMEthaneMan I said survive better not what they couldn't surive with out.

Comment: I find the concept of "hundreds of years long seasons" very confusing. In the winter most species would get wiped out. The long seasons don't really allow a single species to adapt to all the conditions, as several generations pass between one extreme and the other. As for humans? Unless they had a lot of tech available they would die :)

Comment: I think we need more info about temperature extremes, and the local flora and fauna.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming there is no realistic way off the planet and they have access to genetic engineering (or enough time to start a breeding program to get these changes underway), then the humans will have to cycle between "Maasai" and "Inuit" body forms.

In the long summers, the "Maasai" body form provides the ability to travel long distances across savanna terrain on foot, as well as adaptations for heat and conservation of moisture. Advanced genetic engineering would increase the ability to retain water, operate biological systems at elevated temperatures (maybe incorporating a heat sink organ) and possibly other boutique enhancements like improved eyesight, to spot potential predators or prey at long distances.

[image: Maasai]

As the planet enters "fall", the biology gradually changes and succeeding generations become shorter, increase body fat and change their proportions to minimize surface area to retain heat when the winter finally arrives. Increased metabolic activity to generate heat, and perhaps changes to the facial structure to increase the size of sinuses so air can be pre moistened and warmed before being drawn into the lungs would also be beneficial. When spring comes, the cycle will change and humans will gradually change back into their "summer" form over a few generations.

[image: Innuit]

These are fairly minimal changes, and predicted on the idea that if they are printed into the DNA, the people can survive even if technology fails or they are somehow cast into a dark age. Basic human smarts and access to stone tools can allow you to survive in *any* environment using neolithic technology; the Ancestors did just that and even *walked around the world*, settling almost everywhere on the planet using only neolithic technology.

Answer (score 3):

That would depend on their technology level. The main problem is going to be the centuries long winter.

You would want cold adaptation for the winter period, possibly combined with hibernating or something to allow food to still be found. For example if the winter food source is fish then adaptations to allow hunting and living in and around freezing water would be valuable.

When summer comes those winter adaptations would be counter-productive so you would want to drop them and instead optimize for the summer conditions.

But the main adaptation you should make is to head for the equator where seasons have much much smaller impact.

Comment: What about on the other sides of the equator. To have Summer and winter implies that like earth they both exist on the planet at the same time, perpetually swapping hemispheres (north and south). Humans would become migratory in that case, swapping sides every time the seasons swapped to stay in perpetual summer.

Answer (score 2):

More intelligence and physical prowess so they can figure out how to build a new/fix the old spacecraft to get off that rock.

You really need good shelter to protect from the elements which could handle many of the physical issues faced.  More important would be being able to ingest local foods.  If the gravity is a bit different then some physical changes to better handle that, which ever way it goes (up or down) (the strength not the direction!)

But really the human body is pretty resilient and can handle a very wide range of conditions.  So you'd need more specific challenges on the planet for them to need to overcome.